Expo: How to add a "folder reference" to the iOS Xcode project
I'm building an React Native app with Expo.  I need to add a reference to a folder containing multiple files into my iOS Xcode project so that all the files are built into the IPA.  I can do this manually by updating the Xcode project myself but that isn't the expo way of doing things and I'm pretty sure would not work with an EAS build.  Is there an expo plugin or something that can create this folder reference at build time?
Note, I will need to do something similar for Android at some point but I'm only focusing on iOS at the moment.
